# How to convert my cucumber project to run in parallell?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, junit, cucumber

Hi I currently have a large project where i run my cucumber tests, I am running these at night but im finding the jenkins build keeps breaking after an hour or so, so I want to now run my tests in parallel.

Is this possible to do with an existing project, my project is set up with the feature files, steps,runner etc in the src/test/java directory 
[image]

and my test runner looks like this

```
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/test/java/noting/feature_files/"},
    glue = {"noting.steps", "noting.hooks"},
    tags = {"@regression"},
    monochrome = true,
    plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json", "rerun:target/rerun.txt"}
)

public class MainRunner {



}
```

Is there a way to convert this to run in parallel, maybe by annotation or feature package?

Comment: https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/

Comment: Thanks but i dont understand the Scenario Outlines feature file, does this group all the feature files together or something?

Comment: U should look at this - https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/. Search for scenario outline. Basically it runs a specific scenario with different data sets.

Comment: Oh ok, I have numerous scenarios outlines, my main question is how do i run parallel tests form the main runner? It doesnt seem to be possible and all i can see is that i add the scenarios to to resources file and add the surefire plugin, but cant seem to see anyway to run the from the main runner ?

Comment: with junit u cannot run in parallel by using the runner. U have to use maven. with testng runner it is possible to run directly.Else u can run by using threads option from command line. https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/#cli